# Importing a class from a jar file into IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I'm having difficulty importing a class and method from a jar file I've created into my .java file in IntelliJ. It's a simple method to print to the console and contains the following.

```
public class gazutils {
    public static print(Object text){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to import this  with

```
import gazutils.*
```

I get *cannot resolve symbol 'gazutils'*

I am creating the .jar file and importing it into the project structure as follows:

**Project Structure > Artefacts > Add > Jar > From modules with Dependencies**

Then

**Build > Build Artefacts**

I then copy the .jar file into the project structure I want to use the .jar file in and

**Right Click the jar > Add as Library**

This adds it as a dependency, but I still don't seem to be able to access or import the class or method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `gazutils` is a `class` and not the name of a `package`

and `import gazutils.*` implies import all that is part of the package `gazutils` ; which doesn't exist , and hence the failure!

A good Idea is to put your class in a package and then `import` that `packageName.yourClassName`

So :

```
package somePackage;
//imports and other stuff...
public class gazutils {
public static print(Object text){
    System.out.println(text);
}
}
```

In your target where you put the Jar :

```
import somePackage.gazutils;
```

Comment: That did it, including a package fixed it. Cheers